# SSRS How do I hide the values from showing in a report if the parameter is set to false?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS I have a boolean parameter called DeclinedDate.  If I set this to false I want the column declineddate to be hidden and not use the data in any sum totals.  Basically if I set it to false I want it to treat that column like it doesn't exist in the report.

I am able to get the column hidden but the values are still being totaled in other columns.

Comment: You'll need to share more info, there's not enough to go on here. Edit your question and show some sample data and expected result. Include the expression for the SUMs you currently have and show your report design so it can be put into context. I'll put a generic answer in that might help, but if not, please add the extra info as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you current SUM expression is something simple like

```
=SUM(Fields!myAmountField.Value)
```

then you will have to do something like this.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!DeclinedDate.Value = False, 0, Fields!myAmountField.Value))
```